# React - how to add fontsize into React.createElement?

Tags: reactjs, fonts, createelement

Am a little of a newbie on the block and learning React - I have this segment of a function below:

```
AlertNotifications.prototype.render = function () {
    return (React.createElement("div", null, this.props.alerts.map(function (alert) { return React.createElement(MessageBar, { messageBarType: alert.type === AlertType.Urgent ? MessageBarType.severeWarning : MessageBarType.warning, isMultiline: false },
        alert.message,
        alert.moreInformationUrl ? React.createElement("a", { href: alert.moreInformationUrl }, strings.MoreInformation) : ''); })));
};
return AlertNotifications;
```

I need to alter the fontsize of the returned DIV - can you please let me know what I need to alter - or add to the above to alter the fontsize to Arial 16px?

Many thanks in advance

G

Answer (score 1):

Try to use this one:

```
React.createElement("div", {
    style: {
      "font-size": "16px"
    }
  }, /* Put here what you need to insert in div */)
```

So, basically, the second attribute in React.createElement is used for attributes.

Comment: This is probably the easiest answer, but for the style prop camel case is usually easier: `fontSize: "16px"`

Answer (score 0):

You can add a class and style it.

```
React.createElement('div', {class-here}, .......)
```